# Is $l^2$ norm differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

For $l^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\frac{d\|x\|_2}{dx} = \frac{x}{\|x\|_2} $, so $d\|x\|_2$ is differentiable  wherever $x \neq 0$.

is the norm differentiable at $x=0 \in \mathbb R^d$? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that it were. Then by the chain rule, if $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a unit vector, then $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(t) := \|tv\|_2 = |t|$ would be a differentiable function, yielding a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

If we suppose that the norm $||.||$ is differentiable at $0$ then by definition we have
$$||0+h||=||h||=||0||+L(h)+o(||h||)=L(h)+o(||h||)$$
where $L$ is linear, hence we have 
$$1=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{||h||}L(h)+o(1)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{||-h||}L(-h)+o(1)=-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{||h||}L(h)+o(1)=-1$$
which is a contradiction.